# Java Arraylist.remove removes first occurrence instead of index, even though I input an int in?

Tags: java, arraylist

Arraylist.remove removes first occurrence instead of index, even though I input an int in `.remove(int i)`?
Let’s I have a arraylist “numbers” of random amount of numbers, for this example lets say we have {1,3,5,2,4,6}

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
aList.add(1);
aList.add(3);
aList.add(5);
aList.add(2);
aList.add(4);
aList.add(6);
```

I want to remove all odd numbers based on their indices. I have created another Arraylist containing their indices through:

```
int origSize = numbers.size();
for (int i = 0; i < origSize; i++) {
            if (numbers.get(i) % 2 != 0) {
                numbers.add(numbers.get(i));
                remover.add(i);
            }
```

For some reason, when I use the .remove function to remove an element based on its index, it removes the first occurrence. 
My syntax is right or, I am doing .remove(int i) :

```
        for (int i = (remover.size() - 1); i>=0; i--) {
            numbers.remove(remover.get(i));
        }
```

In my example, 5 occurs at index 2. But running `.remove(remover.get(i))`, which should be `.remove(2)` removes the first occurrence of 2… 
Ultimately, I get {3,5,4,6} because it removes the 2,1 and 0 instead of those indices. Why is this happening?

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I think you want remove(int) signature

Comment: @SergiiGetman 1. OP doesn't use for-each loop. 2. In each loop there are additions to one list and removals from other.

Comment: remover.get() will return an Integer, not an int.

Comment: So basically I cannot use an `ArrayList<Integer> remover = new ArrayList<Integer>()`; to store the indices? I have to find another approach to store the indices? Does anyone have a suggestion for me, because the amount of numbers/indices has to be flexible.

Comment: The "DUP" comes out of the fact that he is inadvertently using the **wrong** remove method. That is why I put an additional comment there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you have a `List<Integer>`, if you want to call [`remove(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)), you need to pass in an `int`. If you want to call [`remove(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)), you need to pass in an `Integer`. `Integer` inherits from `Object`. `int` does not.

If you find you are calling the wrong one, cast your `int` to an `Integer` or vice versa using `numbers.remove((int) ...)` or `numbers.remove((Integer) ...)`.

Comment: To clarify, an Integer is not the same as an integer. An Integer is an object.

Comment: @kwantuM An integer is not the same as an `int`.

Comment: So basically I cannot use an `ArrayList<Integer> remover = new ArrayList<Integer>()`; to store the indices? I have to find another approach to store the indices? Does anyone have a suggestion for me, because the amount of numbers/indices has to be flexible.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that's exactly what I said.

Comment: You can change this line: `numbers.remove(remover.get(i));` to `numbers.remove((int) remover.get(i));`. This will make it work.

Comment: @kwantuM No, you said `Integer` != integer, but that's not very relevant to the subject. For example `long` and `char` are also integers.

Comment: But it seems like even if I load the element of the remover arraylist into an integer variable first, e.g. initiating a `int index = remover.get(i)` and load the index into the .remove `remove(index)` function it does not work?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik well alright, I should've said `int` then :)

Comment: @marstran thanks your method solved it. But why would defining an the index as a `int`, like in my previous comment, not solve the problem?

Comment: @kwantuM It's not just hair-splitting, there are problems where the issue is exactly the confusion between `int` and general integer (overflows).